# Chrome screen distorted in places

Tags: graphics, ati, google-chrome, fglrx

Please refer to following 3 images. Screen is not rendered correctly on mouse hover. 
[image: Corrupt Display - screenshot 1]
[image: Corrupt Display - screenshot 2]

The display gets corrected as long as I move the mouse again - so this problem is more of an annoyance, than any thing else. I have updated chrome and my updates are latest (15.04). 
Only thing is that I am not using AMD fglrx drivers. Last time I used them, kernel complained as being tainted and my backlight controls stopped working. Any suggestions please
[image: Additional Drivers]

Comment: Which `fglrx` driver did you use? `-updates` or normal?

Comment: fglrx-updates : The second one in the pic.

Comment: Try the normal one then. `-updates` usually has beta versions, which tend to be buggy.

Comment: ok , using fglrx , seems to have done the trick .  My back light is working as intended and this screen distortion seems to have gone. Will watch for a little more time, and then mark this question solved. Thanks

Comment: Should I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you tried `fglrx-updates`, I recommend using just `fglrx`. The `updates` version tends to be buggy, since it's mainly beta releases.